# Closing web banner that blocks the page Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm intending to do scraping on [this website](http://www.metrocuadrado.com/web/inmuebles/venta/). I've been doing this quite nicely for the last weeks, but today they added a publicity banner that shows the publicity and blocks the elements in the page from being clicked. There is an X that closes this banner (but it does not re-directs me to a new website, it just hides the banner and make all the elements in the page clickable again.

I am trying

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id={0}]".format(bannerid)).click()
```

where bannerid is `"sas_closeButton_6077476"`, but I get the error

> File
>   "/home/vladimir/Documents/Projects/Real-Estate_Market/metrocuadrado_get_links.py",
>   line 52, in get_links
>       close_banner(driver, "sas_closeButton_6077476")   File "/home/vladimir/Documents/Projects/Real-Estate_Market/metrocuadrado_get_links.py",
>   line 12, in close_banner
>       browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id={0}]".format(bannerid)).click()
>   File
>   "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=sas_closeButton_6077476]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.22,platform=Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64)

I don't know what to make out of this. Basically the element does not exist (however when I look at the HTML code I see that this element exists during a period of time corresponding to the "living time" of the banner. How can I close this banner?

I appreciate your help.

UPDATE:

I am working with this code now:

```
def close_banner(browser, bannerid):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='{0}']".format(bannerid)).click()


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

website = "http://www.metrocuadrado.com/web/inmuebles/venta/"
driver.get(website)  # loads the page
time.sleep(7)

# filters sites from Bogota
ciudad_filtro = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ciudad_filtro")
while True:
    try:
        ciudad_filtro.click()
        break
    except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
        close_banner(driver, "sas_closeButton_6077476")

time.sleep(1)
ciudades = ciudad_filtro.find_elements_by_css_selector("option")
for ciudad in ciudades:
    if ciudad.text == "Bogotá D.C.":
        ciudad.click()
        break
time.sleep(10)

# orders sites from the newest
ordenar_filtro = driver.find_element_by_id("rb_ordenar")
while True:
    try:
        ordenar_filtro.click()
        break
    except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
        close_banner(driver, "sas_closeButton_6077476")
time.sleep(1)
ordenes = ordenar_filtro.find_elements_by_css_selector("option")
for orden in ordenes:
    if orden.text == "Más nueva":
        orden.click()
        break
```

After this code there goes more code that iterates over a paginator in order to get some information from each page. In this code the `close_banner` function is also used, but it's too long to copy. The mistake however occurs in the code shown above. Also, sorry for the bad practise of waiting for the websites with a `time.sleep()` instead of a wait given by the selenium module.

This is a view of the banner from my iPad

[image]

Comment: i see in the stack trace this //[@id=sas_closeButton_6077476] which is not a valid selector, * or tag is missing, make sure the right selector is passed.I also see some conditions that are not a good practice like while True, you should wait few seconds for the element and if the element is found then click it.Also make sure the page is loaded first.

Comment: If the banner always appear then wait until the button is visible and click it.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem - missing quotes around the placeholder, replace:

```
"//*[@id={0}]".format(bannerid)
```

with:

```
"//*[@id='{0}']".format(bannerid)
```

Or, you can simply use the `find_element_by_id()` method directly:

```
browser.find_element_by_id(bannerid).click()
```

---

Note that you might also be having a "timing" issue. Try to [wait for the presence of the element via `WebDriverWait` and `presence_of_element_located` expected condition](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: I tried with element by id but it didn't work, let me check waiting for the element to be clickable.

Comment: Now I'm getting a `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible`

Comment: @VladimirVargas okay, can you please update the question with the code you are executing now? Thanks.

Comment: I've posted it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @VladimirVargas thanks! For some reason I don't see the banner you are trying to catch..when is it appearing?

Comment: As soon as I load the website

Comment: I added a picture of it. The X is not shown because I'm posting from my iPad and the formatting is different